TensorFlow Liteの出力がPC上と異なる
Spresense IDEでTensorFlow Liteを搭載しようとしていますが、モデル出力がPC(python)上では問題ないのに対し、同モデル、同入力値でSpresense上で実行すると異なる値となってしまいます。入力方法が誤っているのか、出力の取り方が誤っているのか教えて頂けると助かります。
モデル

入力8、出力2
隠れ層：1層、ユニット10
量子化：int8

出力結果

PC上(python)：出力1=70, 出力2=90
Sprecense：出力1=124, 出力2=127 ←最大値に達してしまっている。

ソース
  #define TFLM_TENSOR_ARENA_SIZE  (1 * 1024)      // actual_arenasize:532byte

  int ret = 0;
  u_char i;
  tflm_runtime_t rt;
  tflm_config_t config = { .cpu_num = 1 };
  void *network;

  // 入力データ(正規化/量子化後)
  int8_t inputdata[8] = {-44,-119 ,-58 ,-98 ,-3 ,-63 ,-7 ,-89};
  const void *inputs[1] = { inputdata };       // モデル引き渡し用入力型

  // modelの読み込み/初期化
  network = alloc_tflite_network("model_quantized.tflite");  // SDcardから読み込み
  ret = tflm_initialize(&config);
  ret = tflm_runtime_initialize(&rt, network, TFLM_TENSOR_ARENA_SIZE); // actual:530byte 

  // 推論実行
  ret = tflm_runtime_forward(&rt, inputs, 1);
  
  // 出力取得
  outpt_cnt = tflm_runtime_output_shape(&rt, 0, 1);     // 出力数取得
  TfLiteTensor *var = tflm_runtime_output_variable(&rt, 0);
  printf("出力(量子化復元前)\n");
  for (i = 0; i < outpt_cnt; i++){
    printf(" output[%u]=%d\n", i, var->data.int8[i]);
  }

  tflm_runtime_finalize(&rt);
  destroy_tflite_network(network);


確認したこと(spresense上で)
入力数：tflm_runtime_input_shape(&rt, 0, 1) = 8 ⇒OK
出力数：tflm_runtime_output_shape(&rt, 0, 1) = 2 ⇒OK
量子化：zeropoint,scale 入力/出力ともにPC/spresense一致 ⇒ OK
モデル"model_quantized.tflite"を「SDカードから読み込み」、「C変換後組み込み」でそれぞれ実行。結果同じ
⇒モデルの取り込みに失敗していることはなさそうなので、そもそも入力が誤っているのかと思った次第です。
